# How to find the normal vector of the contact point between two sprites

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, sprite-kit, sprite

I am creating a game where the character can jump in the direction opposite of the surface he lands on. For example if he is on the ground he can only jump up. If he is on a right edge he can only jump left...etc etc.. Currently I have set up my SKNodes into leftWall, rightWall, bottomSurface, topSurface and have a huge if/else... this works but will become way more complicated as I add different surfaces with different angles etc...

I thought a better way to implement this would be to find the normal vector direction at the point of contact between the character sprite and a general wallNode sprites.

Can anyone help me determine A) the point of contact between sprites assuming the character has a circle physics body and the walls are always straight edges. and B) the normal to the contact point
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the vector or angle of impact will do you much good as your player's jump would likely be in an ark. As such, hitting the same surface at different points of the player's jump ark would yield different results.

I suggest you use unique category bit masks for your surfaces. A more advanced version of that would be to use only one category and utilize the SKSpriteNode's dictionary property to hold the angle value.

Based on the contact data you can then set the correctly angled jump for your player.

Comment: actually ill be applying a constant velocity in the direction normal to the surface. this presents a problem if, for example, the surface is rotating in which case I would need to know the normal direction. Any idea on how I can get it?

Comment: @Jeremy - If I understand you correctly, no gravitational force is being used. If that is the case you can calculate, and store, the player's angle of movement by his changes of x & y position as he moves. You can then calculate the impact angle of the player to the wall by using the wall's zRotation property and set an according vector for the player. Obviously you will need to use a standard zero reference angle like the bottom of the screen for all these calculations.

Comment: sorry I am very new to iOS dev and spritekit. Can you show me an example of how you would do that?